# Formatting of text in label of VMD

Tags: vmd

I want to change the text formatting in the label's properties in VMD, as I want to use 1-based indexing rather than 0-based indexing. For now, %i in Format gives index on the screen, but I want to use serial i.e. the numbering of atoms starts from 0 instead. How can we do that? Thanks.

With best regards

Comment: Are you looking for ways to change what gets printed on the screen when you select an atom in VMD?

Comment: Yes, change what is displayed on the screen of the vmd as I click on the atom.

Comment: https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/vmd-1.7.1/ug/node202.html Please check this link. It might give you some pointers

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but can you update us now that it has been 6+ months since you asked this question? Have you found the answer? Are you still actively in need of an answer? Was the comment by @HemanthHaridas helpful?